# Generating PBKDF2 keys in C# and NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt a byte array in C# using AES192 and a PBKDF2 password/salt based key and decrypt the same data in NodeJS.  However my key generation produces different results in both NodeJS and C#.

The C# code is as follows:

```
    private void getKeyAndIVFromPasswordAndSalt(string password, byte[] salt, SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm, ref byte[] key, ref byte[] iv)
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
        key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(symmetricAlgorithm.KeySize / 8);
        iv = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(symmetricAlgorithm.BlockSize / 8);
    }

    private byte[] encrypt(byte[] unencryptedBytes, string password, int keySize)
    {
        RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesEncryption.KeySize = keySize;
        aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
        byte[] key = new byte[keySize];
        byte[] iv = new byte[128];
        getKeyAndIVFromPasswordAndSalt(password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("$391Ge3%£2gfR"), aesEncryption, ref key, ref iv);
        aesEncryption.Key = key;
        aesEncryption.IV = iv;
        Console.WriteLine("iv: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(aesEncryption.IV));
        Console.WriteLine("key: {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(aesEncryption.Key));
        ICryptoTransform crypto = aesEncryption.CreateEncryptor();
        // The result of the encryption and decryption            
        return crypto.TransformFinalBlock(unencryptedBytes, 0, unencryptedBytes.Length);
    }
```

The NodeJS code reads like this:

```
    crypto.pbkdf2("Test", "$391Ge3%£2gfR", 1000, 192/8, (err, key) => {
        var binkey = new Buffer(key, 'ascii');
        var biniv = new Buffer("R6taODpFa1/A7WhTZVszvA==", 'base64');
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes192', binkey, biniv);
        console.log("KEY: " + binkey.toString("base64"));
        var decodedLIL = decipher.update(decryptedBuffer);
        console.log(decodedLIL);
        return;
    });
```

The IV is hardcoded as I can't figure out how to calculate that using pbkdf2.  I've looked through the nodeJS docs for more help but I'm at a loss as to what's going on here.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that this is not how IVs are intended to be used – you should generate a random IV for every encryption call and send it alongside the ciphertext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the issues I see is the encoding of the pound sign (`£`). `crypto.pbkdf2` encodes the password and salt to a binary array by default, where each character is truncated to the lowest 8 bits (meaning the pound sign becomes the byte 0xA3).

However, your C# code converts the salt to ASCII, where each character is truncated to the lowest 7 bits (meaning the pound sign becomes the byte 0x23). Also it uses the Rfc2898DeriveBytes constructor that takes a String for the password. Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhe81fz4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't say what encoding is used to convert the string to bytes. Fortunately, Rfc2898DeriveBytes does have [another constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148161%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes a byte array for the password and also takes an iteration count parameter, here 1000.

Accordingly, you should convert the password and salt strings to byte arrays by truncating each character to 8 bits, just like Node.js does by default. Here is an example:

```
var bytes=new byte[password.Length];
for(var i=0;i<bytes.Length;i++){
  bytes[i]=(byte)(password[i]&0xFF);
}
```

Comment: That sorted it, thank you.  I hadn't realised that they both defaulted to different character encodings.

Comment: Can I please get an example of how to convert password and salt strings to byte arrays by truncating each character to 8 bits?I am really not able to figure it out on my own.A sample will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.